# Alineación dos elementos con d-flex en Vuetify

Tags: html5, flexbox, vuetify

En esta situación, que dentro de una columna que va a ocupar todo el ancho, tengo dos elementos un span y un v-btn, ¿Cómo puedo alinear el span a la izquierda y el v-btn a la derecha?

```html
<v-row>
  <v-col cols='12' class='d-flex'>
    <span class="text-h6"> Texto </span>
    <v-btn @click="actualizar()">Actualizar</v-btn>
  </v-col>
</v-row>
```

He probado con las clases de https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/flex/#flex-justify pero no logro alinearlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

agrégale la clase **justify-space-between** a tu columna. A mí me funcionó de esa manera.

```
<v-row>
 <v-col cols='12' class='d-flex justify-space-between'>
  <span class="text-h6"> Texto </span>
  <v-btn @click="actualizar()">Actualizar</v-btn>
 </v-col>
</v-row>
```